# Calculation of brightness temperature in Kelvin from Landsat 8, Band 10

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat-8

I tried to use expression to obtain the brightness temperature, It is showing some error.

Can anyone help me with this error?

I have used the co-efficient for band 10 given in metadata of Landsat 8,
Radiance Multiplier = 0.0003342
Radiance Add = 0.1
K1 = 774.89 , K2 = 1321.08.
Conversion from DN to Radiance
y = mx + b,  y is going to be the TOAr that you want.
m is the Radiance Multiplier
x is the raw band
b is the Radiance Add.
Convert Radiance into degrees kelvin
degree Kelvin = K2 / ln(k1/TOAr + 1)

error :

> 'BT: Layer error: Image.parseExpression: Expression parse error at
> character 18:'(1321.08/(Math.log(774.89)/((0.0003342*DN)+0.1+1))))',

code used is given below.

```
//Image collection.
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
var image = l8.filterDate('2016-03-18', '2016-03-19')
            .filterBounds(table)
            .median()          
            .clip(table);
//Calculation of brightness temperature.
var BT = image.expression(
  '(1321.08/(Math.log(774.89)/((0.0003342*DN)+0.1+1))))',
  {
    DN : image.select('B10')
  }).addBa;
Map.addLayer(BT, {min:200, max:300}, 'BT');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues. Following script, where I assumed an arbitrary 'table' geometry, fixes all of them and works as expected.

```
var table = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-112.338671875, 39.65422653179268],
          [-112.338671875, 36.47197808908327],
          [-106.362109375, 36.47197808908327],
          [-106.362109375, 39.65422653179268]]], null, false);

//Image collection.
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
var image = l8.filterDate('2016-03-22', '2016-03-23')
            .filterBounds(table)
            .median()          
            .clip(table);

//Calculation of brightness temperature.
var BT = image.expression(
  '(1321.08/(log(774.89)/((0.0003342*DN)+0.1+1)))',
  {
    DN : image.select('B10')
  }).rename('BT');

print(BT);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["BT"],
                     "min":381.9242348856052,
                     "max":418.5242920858204,
                     "gamma":1};

Map.centerObject(BT);
Map.addLayer(BT, imageVisParam, 'BT');
```

I got following result in GEE code editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

the formula in the first picture tells us we need to use radiance to calculate the brightness temperature, I am not sure whether we can use B10 to calculate directly. In the description of L1_T2 data(the second picture), I find the ST_TRAD band, and it represents radiance. I am confused that which band I need to use to calculate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).